# NServiceBus - Unable to send message

Tags: nservicebus

I followed the [Getting Started With NServiceBus - Code First Article](http://docs.particular.net/samples/step-by-step/) and when I attempt to send a message from the Client application (NServiceBusDemo.Client) I get the following exception:

> 2013-05-27 12:27:50,514 [7] ERROR NServiceBusDemo.Client.SendOrder
>   [(null)] <(nu ll)> - Problem occurred when starting the endpoint.
>   Common.Logging.ConfigurationException: The destination queue
>   'server@jasper' cou ld not be found. You may have misconfigured the
>   destination for this kind of mes sage
>   (NServiceBusDemo.Messages.Commands.PlaceOrder) in the
>   MessageEndpointMappin gs of the UnicastBusConfig section in your
>   configuration file. It may also be th e case that the given queue just
>   hasn't been created yet, or has been deleted. -
>   --> NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException: Failed to send message t o address: [server@jasper] --->
>   System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: The queu e does not exist or
>   you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operat ion.

It's been a long time since I used NServiceBus but I do recall having to add the message endpoint mappings (not mentioned in the tutorial) which I have done:

```
  <UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit">
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="NServiceBusDemo.Messages" Endpoint="NServiceBusDemo.Server"/>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

When I look in the Message Queuing Console I have the following private queues created:

- nservicebusdemo.client
- nservicebusdemo.client.retries
- nservicebusdemo.server
- nservicebusdemo.server.retries
- nservicebusdemo.server.timeouts
- nservicebusdemo.server.timeoutsdispatcher

Comment: I'm curious, is "jasper" the name of your computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that the the code from the article explicitly specified the endpoint name "Server" (which I had changed). As @UdiDahan pointed out on twitter, **this takes precedence over the MessageEndpointMappings** and is the reason why the mappings were not mentioned in the article.

I updated my client code to *not* specify the endpoint and therefore use the settings in app.config:

```
public class SendOrder : IWantToRunAtStartup
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Run()
    {
        string product;
        while ((product = Console.ReadLine()) != "q")
        {
            Bus.Send(new PlaceOrder() { Product = product });
        }          
    }

    public void Stop()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You should mark the correct answer as... Well, as answer. That's easier for people to see what is the right answer. I thought your answer was something like a follow up question at first :)

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt you have to wait for 2 days before you can mark your own answer as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (i.e. same error) but the solution to my problem was different from yours.  I wanted to share here to make sure others don't have the same issue.

For me, the problem was happening because the console application wasn't starting.  I had to set the startup project as the solution, which is configured to start both the web app and the console app.  After doing this, everything started working.

I hope that helps someone.